# div height by percentage doesn't works on Chrome 63

Tags: html, css, html-table

I found style is broken in my website without change on code when I use Chrome. Even though, when I confirmed with Firefox and Safari, it works well and I remember it also worked before I update Chrome.

I tried to figure out what this causes, but could not.

https://jsfiddle.net/3ttou4jv/1/

```
table {
  height: 100%;
}

td {
  height: 100%;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #565656;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.td-inner {
  height: 100%;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #e1e1e1;
}
```

Is there mistake on code, or this is the way Chrome's css interpretation?

Comment: The div class above it doesn't have a height set. To make percentage height work the element above it should have a height set like 500px.

Comment: If you are trying to get element to be like screen height I would suggest using "vh" units instead of percentage, as @MarkBaijens said if you want to get percentage to work you need the parent element to have a specified height.

Comment: Chrome did minorly change its interpretation of % height recently. If anyone can find a layout that previously looked the same in *all browsers* but now looks different *only in chrome*, please file a bug at http://crbug.com/new. If no one looks at it quickly, respond here with the issue number.

Comment: Thank you everyone answered or commented!
I could fixed the way AndrewBone answered, but also reported as dgrogan commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this in Firefox and it looked the same as chrome, I think this will answer the underlying issue though.

When you use a percent you are saying be this much of your parent if the parent is 100px tall and you set the child's height to 100% the child will be 100px.

In this instance `.table_root`, `table`'s parent, is just taking up as much space as it needs.

You can fix this by setting `HTML`, `body` and `.table_root` to 100%, which will take up 100% of the screen. Alternatively, you can use vh rather than % vh is [viewport height](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/) 100vh equates to 100% of the viewport height.

**Example with %**

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div>100% example</div>
```

**Example with vh**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div>vh example</div>
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Setting html/body and .table_root to 100% fixes the issue.

```
body,html {
  height: 100%;
}

.table_root {
  height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3ttou4jv/2/